# Making authentication with jwt for socket.io connection. Is this a valid approach

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, socket.io, jwt

i am emitting unAuthorized if the token is not valid and listening that on client side to refresh the accessToken if there was less than 2 attempts by using refreshToken hook which update auth.accessToken and auth.userID which will cause useEffect to run because those are given in dependency array is this a good method if not suggest a good way and is there chance for any side effects

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const makeSocketConnection = () => {
      socket = io(BASE_URL, {
        timeout: 5000,
        query: {
          token: auth.accessToken,
        },
      });

      socket.emit("setup", auth.userID);

      socket.on("setup complete", () => {
        setSocketConnected(true);
      });

      socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        setSocketConnected(false);
      });

      socket.on("connect_error", () => {
        
         toast.error("Connection error : failed to connect to socket");

      });
      
      socket.on("Unauthorized",()=>{
        
        if(retrysMade < maxRetry){
          
          retrysMade++;
          
          refreshToken();
        }
      });

      socket.on("error", (error) => {
        console.error("Socket.IO error:", error);
      });
    };

    makeSocketConnection();
    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
      console.log("disconnected");
    };
  }, [auth.userID, auth.accessToken]);
```

the below is the backend code

```
let server;

mongoose.connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  server = app.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)
  );

  const io = new Server(server, {
    pingTimeout: 60000,
    cors: corsOptions,
  });
  
  io.use((socket, next) => {
    const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
    
    if (typeof token != "string" || !process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
      return next(
        new Error(
          "token not recieved or failed to get secret to verify accessToken"
        )
      );;
    
      // Validate JWT token
      jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
          // If JWT token is invalid or expired, send a 403 Forbidden response
          console.error("JWT validation failed:", err.message);
          return next(new Error("Unauthorized"));
        } else {
          // If JWT token is valid, proceed with the connection
          console.log("Socket connection authorized:", decoded);
          return next();
        }
      });
    
 
  });

  io.on("connection", (socket): void => {
    console.log("intial connection from client");

    socket.on("setup", (userData) => {
      console.log(userData, "setup");

      socket.join(userData);
      socket.emit("setup complete");
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("Socket disconnected:");
    });

    socket.on("join chat", (room) => {
      socket.join(room);
      console.log("join chat", room);
    });

    socket.on("typing", (room) => {
      console.log("typing",room);
      socket.in(room).emit("typing now",{room});
    });
    socket.on("stop typing", (room) => {
     console.log('stop typing')
      socket.in(room).emit("stop typing",{room});
    });

    socket.on("new message", (newMessage: Tmessage) => {
      let chat = newMessage.chat;

      console.log(newMessage, "new message \t \t");

      if (!chat.users) return console.log("chat.users is not defined");

      chat.users.forEach((user) => {
        if (user._id === newMessage.sender._id) return;

        console.log(user._id, "message send to \t \t ");
        socket.in(user._id).emit("message recieved", newMessage);
      });
    });
  });
  
io.use((socket, next) => {
  socket.on("error", (error) => {
    if (error.message === "Unauthorized") {
      // Send a 403 Forbidden response
      socket.emit("unauthorized", {
        message: "You are not authorized to connect.",
      });
    }
  });
  next();
});
  
});
```

Is there any resource to read on this please also mention